# Android MotionEvent constants and methods not found

Tags: android

I'm reading the book "Beginning Android Games" and the code won't compile.

All of these constants are not found in the MotionEvent class:

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP
```

And these methods:

```
event.getX(pointerIndex)
event.getPointerCount()
event.getX(pointerIndex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which API level do you use for your android project ?

It should be at least 2.0 (level 5). For every android method or constant, [look at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX%28int%29). On the gray banner for the name of this field, on the right, there is a version number that indicates the level of Android API that introduced this feature.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I had it set to Android 2.0 which uses SDK Version 7. But in the default.properties file, switching target=android-3 to target=android-5, it now works